# Local DNS override works randomly with Bind

Tags: networking, dns, bind

I have a Bind DNS server on my local network to get *.home resolution, and a forwarders section for every other domains. I also have a local web server which serve some subdomains of *.mydomain.com from the outside, with my ISP box redirecting ports 80/443 to it.

But from any computer within my local network, if I try to access any of the *.mydomain.com address, the IP address returned is my public IP address and the ISP box doesn't redirect the request to my server. I used a workaround by adding the subdomains *.mydomain.com with the local IP address of the server in /etc/hosts on each local computer but it's not perfect since I have to change it if I move a computer to another network, plus I can't do this on my non-rooted Android devices.

The perfect solution would be to have my local DNS overrinding the DNS entries for *.mydomain.com with the local IP instead of the public one. I tried some Bind9 configurations for this, some using the "response-policy" directive, some without it, but in every case, I get the external IP ~50% of the time and I can't figure out why. This happens on every computer I use (some are on Ubuntu, some with Windows), also on my Android phones.

Using `dig @mydns subdomain.mydomain.com` return the local IP so I assume that the Bind configuration is OK, but `dig subdomain.mydomain.com` (or ping) doesn't always return the proper IP. I also tried to disable forwarders for the subdomain like this :

```
zone "mydomain.com" {
    type master;
    file "/etc/bind/db.mydomain";
    forwarders {};
};
```

I flushed the DNS cache of my computers and there is no other DNS server on my network so I don't understand how this can happen. I also tried to log requests on the Bind server and I don't see requests with the external IP address returned (only those with the internal). So where did these requests go through ?

Answer (score 1):

I finally found out what the problem was : my custom DHCP/DNS server was configured for IPv4 only, but my ISP box also provide IPv6 capabilities, so all the DNS requests from the devices on the network where sent on both protocols and half of the time, the request was answered by the ISP box instead of my custom DNS.

I disabled IPv6 for now and the problem is gone. I'll configure it for my custom server later.